Listening on the same port for udp and tcp in elixir
Im writing a dns server purely in elixir just for fun and im struggling to get it to accept udp and tcp on port 53. I was also wonder if anyone had any recommendation for a good library for these tcp and udp sockets in elixir.
I have tried using gen_udp open and gen_tcp listen but keep getting an error.

"keep getting an error" Source code and the actual error would be useful information.

I wrote a DNS server in Elixir, and it listens both on TCP and UDP so you're welcome to read the source code. Basically:
socket_result =
      :gen_udp.open(config()["port"], options)
socket = socket_open(socket_result) 
...
socket_result = :gen_tcp.listen(config()["port"], options)
socket = socket_open(socket_result)


Thank you so much I just got a look at the code you sent me and its exactly what im looking for

If it works, then don't forget to Accept the answer so that others know the problem is solved.
